# Compare time only in linq to sql with time rang

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have datetime column in my data base that get value like `2016-01-23 14:47:00`.
I want to get result from last 2 month between 12:00:00 and 15:00:00.
I make datetime variable but it get today date.

```
var q11 = DateTime.Parse("12:00:00 AM");
var q12 = DateTime.Parse("03:00:00 AM");
cq11 += _db.deliverys.Where(r => r.mainid == item.id && 
                                 r.state == true && 
                                 r.readtime >= q11 && 
                                 r.readtime <= q12).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

So depending on your data set and the larger scope of your solution; this may be a less than ideal solution because I don't think TimeOfDay is translated to sql.  This will pull a dataset into memory with the mainid and state query, and then filter down further in memory using time of day and timespan.

```
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0); //NOON
TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);   //3 PM

var subQuery = _db.deliverys.Where(r => r.mainid = item.id && r.state == true).ToList();

var results = subQuery.Where(q => (q.TimeOfDay > start) && (q.TimeOfDay < end));
```

I tested with an in memory list and it pulled back dates across multiple months.

Comment: I need to get value during 2 month.I gusse your code only compare time for one day.

Comment: @Zenith Updated the answer